# How to add a column to a dataframe by merging index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new to pandas and I am trying to add a column to a dataframe, considering that the new column has its own index.

For example, let's consider the following data:

```
kp = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
val = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
df = pd.DataFrame({"test":val}, index=kp)
```

Now, I would like to add a new column to this dataframe considering that the new index may be different of the one used in df:

```
kp2 = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.0])
val2 = np.array([0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.10])
```

What I want:
[Resulting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDsE7.png)

[image]

kp2 and val2 have the same length, kp and val have the same length but kp and kp2 may have different length and of course, different index. I used index for kp as I wanted the index to be unique and so to merge index when adding a new column. If there is a better solution, feel free to propose.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#your data:
kp = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
val = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5])
kp2 = np.array([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.0])
val2 = np.array([0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.10])
df = pd.DataFrame({"test":val}, index=kp)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"test2":val2}, index=kp2)
```

You can do this simply by using [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method:

```
result=pd.concat((df,df2),axis=1)
```

Finally use [`sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) method:

```
result=result.sort_index()
```

You can do this in 1 line by:

```
result=pd.concat((df,df2),axis=1).sort_index()

#Output of result:
    
    
       test     test2
0.0     0.1     NaN
0.5     NaN     0.6
1.0     0.2     NaN
1.5     NaN     0.7
2.0     0.3     NaN
2.5     NaN     0.8
3.0     0.4     NaN
3.5     NaN     0.9
4.0     0.5     0.1
```

Comment: just checked, indeed!

Comment: @anky thnx for figuring out :)

Comment: Thanks @AnuragDabas. This is the answer I was looking for. Please edit your answer to take into account anky comment. Indeed the last row is not merged in your answer but it works like a charm with anky update.

Comment: already updated as per by anky's comment :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for pandas merge method.

create a new dataframe like the one you created earlier.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"test2":val2}, index=kp2)
```

merge them using dataframe merge command:

```
ddf = df.merge(df2,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True,sort=True)
ddf
```

how='outer' will help you merge 2 dataframes, in a fashion similar to FULL OUTER JOIN of SQL. For other options/arguments look at the docs.[pandas merge docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Merge is also helpful here, you have my upvote :)

Comment: @G.MAHESH Unfortunaltly, my reputation isn't high enough. My upvote isn't accepted :(